# How can I move the null values to the end of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Is there any way to sort the below `String` `Array`

```
[four, null, null, null, good, null, null, null, dogs, null, null, null, swam, null, null, null]
```

to

```
["four", "good", “dogs", “swam”, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

without using any Array methods from the `Array` class.

This is what I did but this is basically copying the same thing

```
String [] newArray = new String [letters.length()];
for(int i=0; i<n+1;i++){
        if (oldArray[i]!=null){
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
        }
```

Comment: You could manually sort the array, there are plenty of examples of bubble sort around

Comment: There is not predefined function for it. You have to write your own algorithm to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] oldArray = { null, "four", null, "good", null, "dogs", null, "swam", null, null, null };
int size = oldArray.length;
String[] newArray = new String[size];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (oldArray[i] != null) {
        newArray[index++] = oldArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
String newa[] = new String[old.length];
Int i = 0;
for(String s:old)
    if(s!=null){
        newa[i] = s;
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always identify the first null in the array and move the other Non-null elements to the left of the marked element.